# actframework run error: org.osgl.exception.UnexpectedException: App not found

Tags: actframework

java code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Act.start("Hello World Demo");
    }
}
```

error message:

```
pid: 1
profile: dev
mode: DEV

zen: Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

四月 14, 2017 11:27:11 上午 act.Act start
信息: loading application(s) ...
四月 14, 2017 11:27:11 上午 act.app.AppScanner scan
警告: . is not a valid app base
四月 14, 2017 11:27:11 上午 org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.6.Final
四月 14, 2017 11:27:11 上午 org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.6.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.osgl.exception.UnexpectedException: App not found. Please make sure your app start directory is correct
at act.Act.start(Act.java:328)
at act.Act.startApp(Act.java:290)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at act.boot.app.RunApp.start(RunApp.java:84)
at act.Act.start(Act.java:631)
at search.doc.App.main(App.java:13)
```

==================================================
Compilation completed successfully, but run App error.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://actframework.org/doc/faq

You need to update the Run configuration and make sure working directory is set correctly:

[image]